# Copy rows from one worksheet to another based on a unique "ID" column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel worksheets (Worksheet A and Worksheet B).
They have the same column headers.
One of the columns "ID", has some equal values in both worksheets.
"ID" is a unique number that never repeats within a worksheet.

I'm trying to compare the ID columns of the two worksheets.
If the ID is the same on a particular row between the two worksheets, copy the rest of the contents of that row from B to A on the row where ID exists in A.

Example of the two Excel sheets.

Worksheet A:

```
ID      Color   Make      Build
A5      red     toyota    corolla
7       blue    nissan    blah
3       red     blahblah  bloo
6       blue    toyota    corolla
9       red     nissan    blah
54      blue    blahblah  bloo
987     red     nissan    blah
432432  white   car       car
```

Worksheet B:

```
ID  Color   Make      Build
3   green   blahblah  bloo
6   blue    toyota    corolla
A5  red     toyota    corolla
7   blue    nissan    SUPERCAR
9   yellow  Tesla     blah
54  blue    blahblah  bloo
987 red     nissan    blah
```

I'm trying to copy the Color/Make/Build cells from Worksheet B to A if the IDs are the same.

For example, row 3 of Worksheet A would become:
7   blue    nissan    SUPERCAR

This is the general idea:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

    Dim A As Worksheet, B As Worksheet, ID As Long

    Set A = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set B = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For i = 2 to 8
        For j = 2 to 8
            If A.Cells(i,1) = B.Cells(j,1) Then
                A.Cells(i,2) = B.Cells(j,2)
                A.Cells(i,3) = B.Cells(j,3)
                A.Cells(i,4) = B.Cells(j,4)
            Else
                Continue

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim a As String
    
    For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    a = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value

    For j = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(j, 1).Value = a Then
        
            ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value
            ws.Cells(j, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value
            ws.Cells(j, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 4).Value
            
        End If
    Next j

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! It does the opposite of what I wanted it to do, but I just had to swap ws and ws2 in "ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value" to copy worksheet B cells to A.

Another question I had was if I wanted it to just grab all the columns without numbering them with those three lines, like instead of 2, 3, 4 I could replace them with a variable (lets say X) and make a for loop around that line saying "for x = 2 to ws.columns.count", correct? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: nevermind about my 2nd sentence, I see you edited your answer

Comment: Glad i could help for `Another question` i would suggest to post new question.